# Composer vcs install on Gitolite

Tags: git, version-control, composer-php, gitolite

I created a library on my gitolite server with a composer.json

```
{
    "name": "package/package-name",
    "type": "library",
    "description": "Wine Extension for Wordpress",
    "keywords": ["Page Management"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Author",
            "email": "author@email.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.2"
    },
    "autoload": {
      "psr-4": { "Prefix\\PackageName\\": "src/" }
    },
    "extra": {
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "master"
        }
    }
}
```

And then I want to include them in other project, so I add on my repositories like this.

```
[
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "git@my-server.com:Library/PackageName"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "package/package-name": "master",
    },
]
```

I have exact the same composer.json file on another library on github. However on Github it works, but not on gitolite. I wonder if this has something to do with the Gitolite, if the Gitolite doesn't support it. Can someone explain to me? on github, the package also not available on Packagist. So I think this should not be the problem.

The error I got from Gitolite:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
    - The requested package package/package-name could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Potential causes:
    - A typo in the package name
    - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
    see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.
```

both "dev-master" or "master" are not working.

but if I require the package like this, it works.

```
{
  "type": "package",
  "package": {
    "name": "package/package-name",
    "version": "dev",
    "type": "package",
    "source": {
        "url": "git@my-server.com:Library/PackageName",
        "type": "git",
        "reference": "master"
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.2",
        "leafo/scssphp": "^0.3.2"
    },
    "autoload": {
      "psr-0": { "Prefix\\PackageName\\": "src/" }
    }
  }
}
```

Has someone idea how to solve this? I would like to use vcs. It would be easier to manage. thank you!

I don't think that stable version the problem like most of them.
[Using private Composer VCS Git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28065395/using-private-composer-vcs-git-repo)
[Composer VCS repository not loading dependancies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29535513/composer-vcs-repository-not-loading-dependancies)
[Optimize multiple Composer VCS repository paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33653873/optimize-multiple-composer-vcs-repository-paths)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a branch, you have to prefix it's name with `dev-`, so it's `dev-master`, not `master`.

Also note that you have to explicitly mention all the repositories where your software resides, otherwise indirect inclusions will not work.

Composer only knows about packages from packagist.org and from repositories in the root `composer.json` file. Including a package that includes another package from your Gitolite would not work.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, like I said on my post, I did tried both "dev-master" or "master". I have exact same composer.json on my server like the one on the github. As I run composer install, it found the composer.json file. The one I tried on Github is also a private repository, so it is impossible to be in packagist.

Comment: I am such an idiot, I found the problem, I made a mistake by require a package name which is different from the root composer.json file. I wrote "package" instead "extension" for root json.